# Second operation on context never ends. One context two repositories in request scope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I have partial interface

```
public partial interface ISponsoredService { GetX(), AddX() }
public partial interface ISponsoredService { GetY(), AddY() }
```

And partial implementations

```
public partial class SponsoredService : ISponsoredService {
     public SponsoredService(
        ISponsoredBrandsRepository sponsoredBrandRepository, 
        ISponsoredDiscountsRepository sponsoredDiscountsRepository) { } 
}

public partial class SponsoredService { GetX(); AddX(); }
public partial class SponsoredService { GetY(); AddY(); }
```

And the problem is with these repositories because they use the same `context` **injected in request scope like services and repositories**.

```
public class SponsoredDiscountsRepository : BaseSponsoredRepository, ISponsoredDiscountsRepository 
{
    public SponsoredDiscountsRepository(
        Context sponsoredContext) : base(sponsoredContext)
    {
    }
}
public class SponsoredBrandsRepository : BaseSponsoredRepository, ISponsoredBrandsRepository  
    {
        public SponsoredBrandsRepository (
            Context sponsoredContext) : base(sponsoredContext)
        {
        }
    }
```

Ninject configuration:

```
        kernel.Bind<Context>().ToSelf();
        kernel.Bind<ISponsoredService>().To<SponsoredService>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISponsoredBrandsRepository>().To<SponsoredBrandsRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISponsoredDiscountsRepository>().To<SponsoredDiscountsRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

And where is a problem?

When I execute `AddX()` and then `GetX()` in the **same HTTP request** the second operation(GetX()) hangs on the connection to the base. It lasts forever and never ends.

But if I do `AddX()` and then in other HTTP request `GetX()` it work. 
Combination `AddY()` and in the same request `GetX()` do not work as well.

What is going on here? Context are not disposed because it's created in request scope. In the same request scope is created `SponsoredService` which contains `repository1` and `repository2` which contains created `context`.

**Edit**: Add implementation of repositories
These two repositories use one generic wchich contains:

```
    protected readonly Context SponsoredContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
```

and all operations:

```
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync()
    {
        return await this.DbSet.ToListAsync();
    }

    GetX() { sponsoredBrandsRepository.GetAsync(); }
    AddX() {
       sponsoredBrandsRepository.GetAsync();
       some operations
       sponsoredBrandsRepository.AddAsync();
    }
```

**Edit** add full code 
**WebAPI:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/sponsored")]
public partial class SponsoredController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly ISponsoredService _sponsoredService;

    public SponsoredController(
        ISponsoredService sponsoredService, 
        IBrandService brandService, 
        ICampaignsService discountService)
    {
        _sponsoredService = sponsoredService;
        _discountService = discountService;
        _brandService = brandService;
    }
}
public partial class SponsoredController
{
    private readonly IBrandService _brandService;

    [Route("brands"), HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBrands()
    {
        try
        {
            var viewModels = await GetBrandViewModels();
            return Ok(viewModels);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            base.Log(e);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    [Route("brands"), HttpPost, ValidateModelStateFilter]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<SponsoredBrandAddOrUpdateViewModel> viewModels)
    {
        try
        {
            await this._sponsoredService.AddOrUpdate(viewModels.Select(vm => (SponsoredBrand)vm));
            return Created("api/sponsored/brands", GetBrandViewModels());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            base.Log(e, viewModels);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }


    private async Task<List<SponsoredBrandListViewModel>> GetBrandViewModels()
    {
        var dbSponsoredBrands = await this._sponsoredService.GetSponsoredBrandsAsync();
        var viewModels =
            dbSponsoredBrands.Select(sponsoredBrand =>
            {
                var viewModel = (SponsoredBrandListViewModel)sponsoredBrand;
                viewModel.Name = (this._brandService.GetBrandByBrandIdAsync(viewModel.BrandId).Result).Entity.Name;
                return viewModel;
            }).ToList();
        return viewModels;
    }
}

  public partial class SponsoredController
{
    private readonly ICampaignsService _discountService;

    [Route("discounts"), HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDiscounts()
    {
        try
        {
            var viewModels = await GetDiscountsViewModels();
            return Ok(viewModels);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            base.Log(e);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
    [Route("discounts"), HttpPost, ValidateModelStateFilter]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscountAddOrUpdateViewModel> viewModels)
    {
        try
        {
            await this._sponsoredService.AddOrUpdate(viewModels.Select(vm => (SponsoredDiscount)vm));
            return Created("api/sponsored/discounts", GetDiscountsViewModels());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            base.Log(e, viewModels);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<SponsoredDiscountListViewModel>> GetDiscountsViewModels()
    {
        var dbSponsoredBrands = await this._sponsoredService.GetSponsoredDiscountsAsync();
        var viewModels =
            dbSponsoredBrands.Select(sponsoredBrand =>
            {
                var viewModel = (SponsoredDiscountListViewModel)sponsoredBrand;
                viewModel.Name = (this._discountService.GetCampaignByCampaignIdAsync(viewModel.DiscountId).Result)?.Entity?.Discount?.Name;
                return viewModel;
            }).ToList();
        return viewModels;
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public partial interface ISponsoredService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount>> GetSponsoredDiscountsAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount>> AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount> sponsoredDiscounts);

}
public partial interface ISponsoredService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount>> GetSponsoredDiscountsAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount>> AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount> sponsoredDiscounts);
}

 public partial class SponsoredService : ISponsoredService
{
    public SponsoredService(
        ISponsoredBrandsRepository sponsoredBrandRepository, 
        ISponsoredDiscountsRepository sponsoredDiscountsRepository, 
        IBrandService brandService, 
        ICampaignsService discountsService)
    {
        _sponsoredBrandRepository = sponsoredBrandRepository;
        _brandService = brandService;
        _discountsService = discountsService;
        _sponsoredDiscountsRepository = sponsoredDiscountsRepository;
    }
}
public partial class SponsoredService
{
    private readonly ISponsoredBrandsRepository _sponsoredBrandRepository;
    private readonly IBrandService _brandService;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredBrand>> GetSponsoredBrandsAsync() => await this._sponsoredBrandRepository.GetAsync();


    public async Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredBrand>> AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<SponsoredBrand> sponsoredBrands)
    {
        // remove
        var dbSponsored = await this.GetSponsoredBrandsAsync();
        foreach (var dbS in dbSponsored)
        {
            if (!sponsoredBrands.Any(s => s.RelatedEntityId == dbS.RelatedEntityId))
            {
                await this.DeleteSponsoredBrand(dbS.Id);
            }
        }

        // new 
        foreach (var newS in sponsoredBrands)
        {
            var brand = (await this._brandService.GetBrandByBrandIdAsync(newS.RelatedEntityId)).Entity;
            brand.BrandRules = new List<BrandRule>
            {
                new BrandRule
                {
                    IsHighlighted = true, Order = newS.Order, ValidTo = newS.To, ValidFrom = newS.From
                }
            }.ToList();
            await this._brandService.UpdateAsync(brand);
        }

        this._sponsoredBrandRepository.Clear();
        await this._sponsoredBrandRepository.Add(sponsoredBrands);
        return null;
    }

}
 public partial class SponsoredService
{

    private readonly ISponsoredDiscountsRepository _sponsoredDiscountsRepository;
    private readonly ICampaignsService _discountsService;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount>> GetSponsoredDiscountsAsync()
        => await this._sponsoredDiscountsRepository.GetAsync();

    public async Task<IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount>> AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<SponsoredDiscount> sponsoredDiscounts)
    {
        // remove
        var dbSponsored = await this.GetSponsoredDiscountsAsync();
        foreach (var dbS in dbSponsored)
            if (!sponsoredDiscounts.Any(s => s.RelatedEntityId == dbS.RelatedEntityId))
                await this.DeleteSponsoredDiscount(dbS.Id);

        // new 
        foreach (var newS in sponsoredDiscounts)
            if (!await this._discountsService.X(newS.RelatedEntityId, newS))
                return null;

        this._sponsoredDiscountsRepository.Clear();
        await this._sponsoredDiscountsRepository.Add(sponsoredDiscounts);
        return null;
    }   
}
```

**Repositories:**

```
    public interface ISponsoredRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity, int>
        where TEntity : Sponsored.Sponsored
    {
        void Clear();
        Task Add(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    }
    public interface ISponsoredBrandsRepository : ISponsoredRepository<SponsoredBrand> { }
    public interface ISponsoredDiscountsRepository : ISponsoredRepository<SponsoredDiscount> { }


public abstract class SponsoredRepository<TEntity> : ISponsoredRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Domain.Sponsored.Sponsored
    {
        protected readonly Context SponsoredContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

        protected SponsoredRepository(Context sponsoredContext)
        {
            SponsoredContext = sponsoredContext;
            DbSet = this.SponsoredContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync()
        {
            return await this.DbSet.ToListAsync();
        }



        public virtual void Clear()
        {
            this.DbSet.RemoveRange(this.DbSet);
            this.SponsoredContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public virtual async Task Add(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            this.DbSet.AddRange(entities);
            await this.SponsoredContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

      public class SponsoredBrandsRepository : SponsoredRepository<SponsoredBrand>, ISponsoredBrandsRepository
    {
        public SponsoredBrandsRepository(
            Context sponsoredContext) : base(sponsoredContext)
        {
        }
    }

     public class SponsoredDiscountsRepository : SponsoredRepository<SponsoredDiscount>, ISponsoredDiscountsRepository
    {
        public SponsoredDiscountsRepository(
            Context sponsoredContext) : base(sponsoredContext)
        {
        }
    }
```

**ContexT:**

```
public class Context
{
    public virtual DbSet<SponsoredBrand> Brands { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SponsoredDiscount> Discounts { get; set; }


    public Context()
    {

    }

}
```

**IoC configuration(Ninject):**

```
       kernel.Bind<Context>().ToSelf();
        kernel.Bind<ISponsoredService>().To<SponsoredService>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISponsoredBrandsRepository>().To<SponsoredBrandsRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISponsoredDiscountsRepository>().To<SponsoredDiscountsRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `AddX` and `GetX`?

Comment: Added pseudo-code and base sponsored repository to concrete implementations.

Comment: Better add real code instead of pseudo one, because that might be important. You may do something like `GetAsync().Result` without await and that will deadlock.

Comment: Nah, everywhere is await.

Comment: If something isn't working, the more **actual** code you can show us the better. You are likely making assumptions about where the problem is - and your assumptions may be wrong.

Comment: Added full code from API to repository.

Comment: I assume you are using a transaction mechanism which commit/rollback at the end of the request. The fact that the processing never ends is most probably that you are stuck in a sql lock mechanism.
Anyway, applying the solution of @davethieben (binding the context InRequestScope) should solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding Context `InRequestScope`, so by default it gets created as Transient scope, and therefore is probably not being disposed/closed.

more on Scopes:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Managing a single `DbContext` in a request is hard. You may have lots of different classes requesting it as a dependency and using it different ways. I ended up with a complex scoping mechanism to manage the DbContexts. However, it may be easier/better to inject a DbContext factory and use `using` to control the lifetime of the DbContext (unit of work pattern), or just `new` it up in your repository (and dispose it).

if you Google "entity framework dbcontext request", you will find many discussions and opinions about the matter. here is a good overview/intro: http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/